# Loop or Array to a lot shifts from rankings?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to a lot of shifts from rankings, and have no idea what formula to use?

Essentially we have a performance score, and a ranking function to find who the top performers are. The higher your ranking, the better likelihood you will receive your first shift choice.

There is only a certain amount of each shift, however.

Please see the below spreadsheet to gain a better understanding. I am looking for a formula that can be entered into the shift column to show what shift each person has. VBA is fine as well.

[image]

Comment: This seems like an underspecified operations research problem. You haven't really spelled out the logic of the schedule. For example, will you give a higher-ranked person their second choice if it allows for a large number of lower-ranked people to have their first choices? There are such potential trade-offs which need to be addressed. Do you have an objective function which you are trying to optimize? No simple formula will work. VBA is probably needed (though you could perhaps set it up in a way that the Solver could be invoked). What have you tried?

Comment: A reasonable heuristic would be to sort the people by rank and then let them pick their shifts on a first-come-first serve basis. Assume that each person will pick the remaining shift which they most prefer (their first choice if still available, else their second choice if still available, etc.) It would be easy enough to code in VBA, but the resulting schedule might not be optimal.

Comment: Each person gets their first choice if the higher they rank, followed by their 2nd, etc. until each shift runs out. I realize the need for a loop in VBA, but VBA is not my specialty.

Comment: not sufficient information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a formula but it will be a big formula. Essentially you will need a series of VLOOKUPs, encapsulated in a series of IF statements.

An example of the logic:

```
IF(Rank<=VLOOKUP(Choice1), Choice1, If(Rank<=(VLOOKUP(Choice1) + VLOOKUP(Choice2), Choice2, IF( ...
```

I would suggest that to reduce the size of the formula you add some additional columns and carry out some of the calculations in the new columns.

For example:

```
T2 becomes =VLOOKUP(G2, $P$1:$R$6, 3, FALSE)
U2 becomes =T2 + VLOOKUP(H2, $P$1:$R$6, 3, FALSE)
```

etc., so that you are looking up the current shift value and adding it to the cumulative total.

Then in `M (Shift)` you have your `IF` statement:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(G2:K2,0,IFNA(MATCH(L2,T2:X2,1)+1,1)),K2)
```

`MATCH` will find out how many columns across the cumulative shift totals the rank is (i.e. whether they get first choice).

`INDEX` will find in the choices columns which shift that choice was.

Note: As mentioned in the comments, this has no handling for rank collision (where more than one person has the same rank).

Why the +1 / `IFNA` / `IFERROR`? Match will step back when it doesn't exceed the total; rank 24 - you want to be Choice 3 - will exceed Choice 2 but not exceed Choice 3. Therefore Match will consider it to be Choice 2, as that was the last one it exceeded. Bump it up one to correctly match Choice 3. This introduces the challenge that it will never match Choice 1, as if it is less than the value in Choice 1, it will not match; this is compensated for by the IFNA which says "If you don't get a match, return 1".

What about the `IFERROR`? Remember we bumped it by +1? This means you could get a value of 6 which won't match any of the choices (for example, if you ended up with more than the number of shift slots). The `IFERROR` bumps it back down to Choice 5.

[image: Associate Shift Pattern]